# How to find the unicode for a text in Notepad++

Tags: oracle, text, unicode, notepad++

I have a webpage that displays data from an Oracle database. On the webpage it seems the text has a space but with the search box i use on the webpage for when i type out the text with a space i don't get any data back. When i copy the value from the Oracle database table with SQL developer into my search box on the webpage i do get the data i want back.

So it seems as if the text is not space but something else. How can i use Notepad++ to find out what character (or Unicode) it really is. This is the text i have.

SCLAS05903_LIP GLOSS_01

Comment: The text you've provided above has a normal space (U+0020).  Did you cut-n-paste the Oracle version?  My default installation of Notepad++ has Plugins->Converter->ASCII->HEX.

Comment: There are a number of things that could be happening here. My first thought would be to start with troubleshooting the webpage/applet portion to make sure messages are being passed in a way that is expected. 

What character set is the database using? Is that different from how the search is passing the query?

Comment: On the Oracle side, you can `select ascii(substr(your_string, 15, 1))` to get the Unicode decimal value of the character at that position in the string. I had something like this happen recently with a zero-width space.